# Unexpected property type or value on using JpegBitmapDecoder.Create() for a jpeg file

Tags: c#, .net

Throws an error "Unexpected property type or value."

```
 using (Stream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read,FileShare.Read))
                {
                     //BitmapDecoder decoder = BitmapDecoder.Create(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
                    BitmapDecoder decoder = JpegBitmapDecoder.Create(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);

                }
```

This issue happens to [this file](https://easyupload.io/io7h3w). Only this particular file has this issue.

When we change `BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad` to `BitmapCacheOption.None` or any other no error is thrown. but the image displayed don't look good. If we open the same image in MSPaint and save it again, then no issues

Comment: Maybe you have some unsupported properties. Try to load the Image bytes (with `File.ReadAllBytes()`) and then get a BitmapSource with something like: `var ms = new MemoryStream([Bitmap Bytes]); var decoder = BitmapDecoder.Create(ms, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default); var bs = (BitmapSource)decoder.Frames[0].GetAsFrozen();`.

Comment: tried it and it didn't worked. Got same error

Comment: Well, I just tried it myself (with the Bitmap you shared) and the BitmapSource is created correctly. Have you used that snippet as I posted it or did you add some *interpretations*?

Comment: used 'BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad' instead of Default. If we change BitmapCacheOption from OnLoad to any other there is no error but the image won't look good. Also, other jpeg images won't be getting displayed

Comment: So, did you actually try it or not? (Note that there's a MemoryStream that receives the bytes, `BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad` is not relevant. The BitmapSource is created correctly - and it shows correctly)

Comment: Thanks, @Jimi. It worked. Ignore my previous comment